# Email Tracking issue incase of multiple receipents

Tags: email, tracking

I had recently made an email tracking system for a friend of mine (we track emails by using image tracking pixels). It is working perfectly fine, except for two cases..(we track emails by using image tracking pixel)
1. If I send a mail with tracking on, and then I open the same mail from “sent item”, it will read the image and will appear as mail has been read since the image was loaded again. And as such even though the receipent hasn’t opened the mail, system will still show it as a read mail
2. How do I track my email incase of multiple recipients? I mean how will i be able to check who has opened and who hasn’t out of the lot. I tried researching over the net, but found only few companies are doing that. Form what I could gather, they were somehow sending unique tracking out to all the recipents. Somehow they are splitting the mails when sent form gmail.

Comment: Did you find any solution for above?

Comment: Nope. Still looking out for a solution.

Comment: @Kevin Did you find anything?